# Retain count of allocated object assigned to a retained property

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, retaincount

In the following code I am expecting the retain count to increase to 2, but it remains at 1 after assignment.  The assignment is to a property with a retain qualifier.  A retain will increment the retain count of the object by 1.  Can anyone explain why the retain count is not incremented?

MyClass.h:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage * imageBackground;
```

MyClass.m:

```
UIImage * IMAGE = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"];
NSLog(@"retain-count(%d)", [IMAGE retainCount]); // returns 1
imageBackground = IMAGE;
NSLog(@"retain-count(%d)", [IMAGE retainCount]); // returns 1, should return 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.imageBackground = IMAGE;
```

Without the `self.` you are not using the property's setter, and thus the retain count won't change since that was just a simple pointer assignment to an ivar.

Comment: Thank You!  This is an answer that solved a lot of problems in my code, I've been scratching my head over it for hours!